# Implement IDisposable on existing class w/ finalizer

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class which currently has a finalizer, but has not implemented IDisposable.
Microsoft states that "It is a version breaking change to add the IDisposable interface to an existing class, as it changes the semantics of the class".
Should the class be 'fixed' and implement IDisposable?

Comment: Why do you need to make the class `IDisposable`? Do you have some resources that _must_ get cleaned up right away?

Comment: In your case, how much code will break? Plenty of projects make "technically" breaking changes that don't affect 99% of users. You have to determine how much stuff will actually break after the change to properly assess the risk/reward of the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you control all the code that uses this class, then you can do it, and update the code to call Dispose. Otherwise, it's not a good idea, as the already existing external code would not call your Dispose().

Answer (score 0):

If you add IDisposable, you need to add code to call the dispose() method in all the code that instantiates your class. If all the code that calls/instantiates your class is not managed by you, it might not be easy and lead to undisposed objects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but basically no. The finalizer is simply a cleanup method called to release memory, there are no promises implied that it will be called by consuming code. IDisposable tells the world that the dispose method MUST be called for an instance of the class, even in the event of an error. If this describes your code, it should have been disposable in the first place, so the answer would be yes. If this is the case however, you'll have to change all the code that consumes your class to make sure they call disposable.